# Evaluating $\frac{48 \sin 386^\circ}{\sin 26^\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

> How to evaluate this kind of expression?
>   $$\frac{48 \sin 386^\circ}{\sin 26^\circ}$$

I know, I am supposed to try first, but I could not figure out what to try. First I thought may be I can make some changes to make it solvable, like, transform it for some trigonometry sum formula or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $360$ degrees is a full circle (or full period of the sine function).

$360 + 26 = 386$

Will the value of the sine change when you add a full period to the argument?

Comment: Yeah, I got it. It is pretty easy, after all. Thanks a lot